# Bad value in a href attribute: "Illegal character in query: >"

Tags: html, url, w3c-validation, entities

I'm getting this error at W3C validator:

> Bad value `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp?term=c.1047A>T` for attribute `href` on element `a`:
>
> Illegal character in query: `>` is not allowed.
>
> ```html
> ar</a> or <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp?term=c.1047A&gt;T" target="_blank">dbSNP<
> ```

I tried change `>` to `&gt;`, but it didn't work, and I need pass this character at URL: `>`. I tried to use `urlencode()` function from PHP and `htmlentities()`, but it didn't solve this error.

A piece of code:

```html
<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=c.-247C&gt;T" target="_blank">ClinVar</a> or <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp?term=c.-247C&gt;T" target="_blank">dbSNP</a>
<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=c.-316T&gt;C" target="_blank">ClinVar</a> or <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp?term=c.-316T&gt;C" target="_blank">dbSNP</a>
```

This code is to generate a direct URL into a external search using all data from the DB and need to use `>` character.

How I can fix this

Comment: Some characters for URL are encoded. You find a full table of their replacements on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to url encode them, not HTML encode them. The correct code for > is `%3E`.